# How to mock React Navigation's navigation prop for unit tests with TypeScript in React Native?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript. For my navigation I use React Navigation and for my unit testing I use Jest and Enzyme.

Here is the (stripped down) code for one of my screen (LoadingScreen.tsx):

```
import styles from "./styles";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationScreenProps } from "react-navigation";

// Is this correct?
export class LoadingScreen extends Component<NavigationScreenProps> {
// Or should I've done:
// export interface Props {
//   navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
// }

// export class LoadingScreen extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This is the LoadingScreen.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default LoadingScreen;
```

When trying to test the screens I came across a problem. The screens expects a prop with a type of NavigiationScreenProps because I'm accessing React Navigations `navigation` prop. Here is the testing file's code (LoadingScreen.test.tsx):

```
import { LoadingScreen } from "./LoadingScreen";
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import * as navigation from "react-navigation";

const createTestProps = (props: Object) => ({
  ...props
});

describe("LoadingScreen", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    let props: Object;
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps({});
      wrapper = shallow(<LoadingScreen {...props} />);
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(View)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is, that `LoadingScreen` expects a `navigation` prop.

I get the error:

```
[ts]
Type '{ constructor: Function; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; valueOf(): Object; hasOwnProperty(v: string | number | symbol): boolean; isPrototypeOf(v: Object): boolean; propertyIsEnumerable(v: string | ... 1 more ... | symbol): boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<NavigationScreenProps<NavigationParams, any>>'.
  Property 'navigation' is missing in type '{ constructor: Function; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; valueOf(): Object; hasOwnProperty(v: string | number | symbol): boolean; isPrototypeOf(v: Object): boolean; propertyIsEnumerable(v: string | ... 1 more ... | symbol): boolean; }'.
(alias) class LoadingScreen
```

How can I fix this?

I think I somehow have to mock the `navigation` prop. I tried doing that (as you can see I imported `*` from React Navigation in my test), but couldn't figure out. There is only `NavigationActions` that is remotely useful but it only includes `navigate()`. TypeScript expects everything, even the state, to be mocked. How can I mock the `navigation` prop?

**Edit 1:** Is the approach of using `NavigationScreenProps` even correct or should I use the `interface Props` approach? If yes how would you then mock than (it results in the same error).

**Edit 2:**
Using the second approach with the interface and

```
export class LoadingScreen extends Component<Props, object>
```

I was able to "solve" this problem. I literally had to mock every single property of the navigation object like this:

```
const createTestProps = (props: Object) => ({
  navigation: {
    state: { params: {} },
    dispatch: jest.fn(),
    goBack: jest.fn(),
    dismiss: jest.fn(),
    navigate: jest.fn(),
    openDrawer: jest.fn(),
    closeDrawer: jest.fn(),
    toggleDrawer: jest.fn(),
    getParam: jest.fn(),
    setParams: jest.fn(),
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    push: jest.fn(),
    replace: jest.fn(),
    pop: jest.fn(),
    popToTop: jest.fn(),
    isFocused: jest.fn()
  },
  ...props
});
```

The question remains: Is this correct? Or is there a better solution?

**Edit 3:**
Back when I used JS, it was enough to mock only the property I needed (often just navigate). But since I started using TypeScript, I had to mock every single aspects of navigation. Otherwise TypeScript would complain that the component expects a prop with a different type.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### Issue

The mock does not match the expected type so TypeScript reports an error.

### Solution

You can use the type `any` ["to opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any).

### Details

As you mentioned, in JavaScript it works to mock only what is needed for the test.

In TypeScript the same mock will cause an error since it does not completely match the expected type.

In situations like these where you have a mock that you know does not match the expected type you can use `any` to allow the mock to pass through compile-time checks.

---

Here is an updated test:

```tsx
import { LoadingScreen } from "./LoadingScreen";
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

const createTestProps = (props: Object) => ({
  navigation: {
    navigate: jest.fn()
  },
  ...props
});

describe("LoadingScreen", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    let props: any;   // use type "any" to opt-out of type-checking
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps({});
      wrapper = shallow(<LoadingScreen {...props} />);   // no compile-time error
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(View)).toHaveLength(1);   // SUCCESS
      expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('LoginScreen');   // SUCCESS
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/3-easy-steps-to-set-up-react-native-with-typescript-jest-and-enzyme-592ca042262f), btw.  I used it to set up the environment to look at this question  

Comment: Thank you! It's funny because, I remember you helping me out with some other critical question I had. Gonna spread your knowledge for you! 

Comment: lol, sounds good.  The knowledge isn't really "mine" so spread it around...knowledge works best when it's shared 

Comment: So what about functional components?

Answer (score 6):

For Typescript users, an alternative approach just for interests sake.

For those that don't like using any, here's a solution that utilises Typescript's Partial utility type and Type assertions (using 'as')

```
import { NavigationScreenProp } from "react-navigation";
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent";

type NavigationScreenPropAlias = NavigationScreenProp<{}>;

describe("Some test spec", () => {
    let navigation: Partial<NavigationScreenPropAlias>;
    beforeEach(() => {
        navigation = {
            dispatch: jest.fn()
        }
    });

    test("Test 1", () => {
        const {} = render(<SomeComponent navigation={navigation as NavigationScreenPropAlias}/>);
    });
});
```

Using Partial, we enjoy our editor/IDE intellisense features, the type assertion 'the 'as' used in the navigation prop definition could be replaced with an any, I just don't like using any if I don't have to.

You could build on the fundamentals in this code snippet to the specific scenario laid out in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have several options:

### 1 - If you are using the `useNavigation` hook:

Example:

```js
const navigation = useNavigation();
const goBack = () => {
        if (navigation.canGoBack()) { navigation.goBack();}
    };
```

- 1.1 - Import this:
  `import * as Navigation from "@react-navigation/native";`
- 1.2 - Before the render method of the test. Obs the `canGoBack` can be `navigate`, `goBack` or the method you want

  ```
  const mockedNavigation = jest.fn();
  jest.spyOn(Navigation, "useNavigation").mockReturnValue({ canGoBack: mockedNavigation });
  ```

...

- 1.3 Check if the method fires:

  ```
  fireEvent.press(button or the element you want);

  expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalled();
  ```

### 2 You are passing the navigation as props

- 2.1 Create a mocked navigator to check that the function is triggered. Obs: put in the json the methods you need

  ```
  const mockedCanGoBack = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);

  const mockedGoBack = jest.fn();

  const mockedNavigation = {
      canGoBack: mockedCanGoBack,
      goBack: mockedGoBack,
  }
  ```
- Pass the navigation prop `mockedNavigation` with the as any. The any will be the typescript work.

  ```
  const screen = render(<ElementYouWant navigation={mockedNavigation as any} ...> ... </ElementYouWant>);
  ```
- 2.3 Fire event and check that funcion is fired. Obs is it necessary that you mock all the functions you need.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's a workaround to preserve type inference in your code, inspired by a solution provided by Brain Adams.**

Imports

Start by importing the necessary modules and components:

```
import React from "react";
import { LoadingScreen } from "./LoadingScreen";
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from "enzyme";
import { View } from "react-native";
import {
  NativeStackNavigationProp,
  NativeStackScreenProps,
} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/core/lib/typescript/src/types";
```

**Define types for route configurations and navigation props**

Define the types for the route configurations and navigation props:

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  LoginScreen: undefined;
};

type LoginProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "LoginScreen">;

type NavigationType = NativeStackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  "LoginScreen",
  undefined
>;

type RouteType = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "LoginScreen">;
```

**Update createTestProps function to include new types**

Extend the createTestProps function with the new types you have defined:

```
const createTestProps = (): unknown & LoginProps => ({
  navigation: {
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  } as unknown as NavigationType,
  route: jest.fn() as unknown as RouteType,
});
```

**Use the types in your unit test**

Now, you can use the types in your unit test:

```
describe("LoadingScreen", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    let props: unknown & LoginProps;
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps();
      wrapper = shallow(<LoadingScreen {...props} />); // no compile-time error
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(View)).toHaveLength(1); // SUCCESS
      expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("LoginScreen"); // SUCCESS
    });
  });
});
```

By using these types, you can ensure that your code is type-safe and can catch errors at compile-time instead of run-time. This will make your code more reliable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super happy with my solution, but I've started mocking only the properties of Navigation that are needed for a specific component, for example:

```js
export function UserHomeScreen({
    navigation,
}: {
    navigation: {
        goBack: () => void;
        navigate: NavigationFunction<UserStackParams, "AddPhoneNumber" | "ValidatePhoneNumber">;
        setOptions: (options: { title: string }) => void;
    };
})
```

In the test, I can provide these as mocks:

```js
const goBack = jest.fn();
const navigate = jest.fn();
const setOptions = jest.fn();

renderer.create(<UserHomeScreen navigation={ { goBack, navigate, setOptions } } />)
```

The definition of `NavigationFunction` is a mouthful as well:

```js
export type NavigationFunction<ParamsList, Routes extends keyof ParamsList> = <T extends Routes>(
    target: Routes,
    params?: ParamsList[T]
) => void;
```

I've not been able to come up with a correct signature for Navigator's functions addListener and removeListener

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer a simpler solution:

```
const mockCallback = jest.fn((val: string) => val);
const component = (  
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Component navigation={{push: mockCallback} } />
    </NavigationContainer>
)

it('clicking on Button takes you to Lists', async () => {
  render(component);
  const toClick = await screen.findByText('Lists');
  fireEvent(toClick, 'press');

  expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```