# How to fix TypeError: navigation.setOptions is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm trying to implement react native test library with jest to my app.

For now I have a problem with the navigation on my component.

When I'm running the test, I've got an error :

```
TypeError: navigation.setOptions is not a function
```

Here is my component:

```
const initialState: StateTypes = {
  toShowAsGridLayout: false,
  isLoadingMoreContacts: false
};

export const Main: FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.appReducer);

  const [state, setState] = useState<StateTypes>(initialState);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: state.isLoadingMoreContacts ? strings.LOADING : strings.ALL_CONTACTS + ' - ' + data.length,
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.changeLayoutButton} onPress={changeLayout}>
          <Text style={styles.changeLayoutText}>{state.toShowAsGridLayout ? strings.LIST : strings.GRID}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    });
  }, [state.isLoadingMoreContacts, state.toShowAsGridLayout])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {renderLayout()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here is a router:

```
const SplashStack = createStackNavigator();
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

export const RootNavigator = () => {
  const { isDataLoading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.appReducer);

  return (
    isDataLoading
      ? <SplashStack.Navigator>
        <SplashStack.Screen name={'SplashStack'} component={Splash} />
      </SplashStack.Navigator>
      : <MainStack.Navigator>
        <MainStack.Screen name={'Main'} component={Main} />
        <MainStack.Screen name={'ContactDetails'} component={ContactDetails} />
      </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And a test itself:

```
import React from 'react';

import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { Main } from '../Main';
import * as redux from 'react-redux';
import strings from '../../constants/strings';
import mocks from '../../mocks';

describe('dispatch mock', () => {
  it('should dispatch mock', () => {
    const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch');
    const useSelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
    const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();
    useDispatchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockDispatchFn);
    useSelectorSpy.mockReturnValue({ data: mocks });

    const { getByText } = render(<Main navigation={({})} />);
    getByText(strings.ALL_CONTACTS);
  });
});
```

How can i fix this error ? What should I pass to navigation props in line :

```
const { getByText } = render(<Main navigation={({})} />);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also face the same issue. With below code changes I have resolved my issue.

**For more info please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569447/how-to-mock-react-navigations-navigation-prop-for-unit-tests-with-typescript-in)**

```
    const createTestProps = (props: Object) => ({
          navigation: {
            navigate: jest.fn(),
            setOptions: jest.fn()
          },
          ...props
        });
    const props = createTestProps({});    
    const { toJSON } = render(<MainScreen {...props} />);
```

[image]

You have to mock the properties and function that your are using in your screen has to be mocked like above. For more info please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569447/how-to-mock-react-navigations-navigation-prop-for-unit-tests-with-typescript-in)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass object with `setOptions` method.

```js
const { getByText } = render(<Main navigation={
  {
    setOptions: (props: { title: string, headerRight: React.FC }) => void
  }
} />);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138351/testing-react-native-app-how-to-fix-navigation-setoptions-is-not-a-function/71141738#71141738) answer might be relevant

Comment: hi, I got the same problem, but your solution, even though it looks good, doesn't work. Namely, I get an error with `setOptions`: `Type '(props: {    headerRight: React.FC;}) => any' is not assignable to type ...`. Also, at the last curly brace, I get `Expression expected.`. I would really appreciate if you could solve this. Thanks.

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris hi, could you please share your minimum reproducible example

Comment: please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138351/testing-react-native-app-how-to-fix-navigation-setoptions-is-not-a-function). It's not reproducible, but you get more info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my purpose solution was very easy, I just added `?.` at the end of `setOptions`

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions?.({ // <--- CHANGED HERE 

      title: state.isLoadingMoreContacts ? strings.LOADING : strings.ALL_CONTACTS + ' - ' + data.length,
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.changeLayoutButton} onPress={changeLayout}>
          <Text style={styles.changeLayoutText}>{state.toShowAsGridLayout ? strings.LIST : strings.GRID}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    });
  }, [state.isLoadingMoreContacts, state.toShowAsGridLayout])
```