# Testing React Native app: How to fix: navigation.setOptions is not a function?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library, react-navigation-v6

Here is the test:

```js
describe('<HomeScreen />', () => {
  it('Renders correctly', () => {

// const setOptions = jest.fn(); // 1
// const setOptions = (navigation: any, route: any) => { } // 2
//   const setOptions = (props: HomeProps) => { } // 3
//  const setOptions = (options: Partial<NativeStackNavigationOptions>) => void // 4

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <HomeScreen navigation={{ setOptions: setOptions }} route={undefined} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>,
    );
  });
});
```

I've tried the solutions that are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68608766/how-to-fix-typeerror-navigation-setoptions-is-not-a-function) and [here](https://www.qandeelacademy.com/questions/how-to-fix-typeerror-navigation-setoptions-is-not-a-function) but they do not work for me.

I think the problem is that I'm using TypeScript and React Navigation v6, because:

1. `const setOptions = jest.fn();`  I get:

   ```
   Type '{ setOptions: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">'.
   ```

   `NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">` is the type I have for the component.

   It's this one: `export type HomeProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;`

   Which later I import as `HomeProps`
2. `const setOptions = (navigation: any, route: any) => { }`

   I get:

   ```
   Type '(navigation: any, route: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(options: Partial<NativeStackNavigationOptions>) => void'.
   ```
3. `const setOptions = (props: HomeProps) => { }`

   I get:

   ```
   Type '(props: HomeProps) => void' is not assignable to type '(options: Partial<NativeStackNavigationOptions>) => void'.
   ```
4. `const setOptions = (options: Partial<NativeStackNavigationOptions>) => void`
   (suggestion of @captain-yossarian)

I get:

```
Type '{ setOptions: (options: Partial<NativeStackNavigationOptions>) => any; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">'.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to import `NativeStackNavigationOptions` type from navigation package ? Your `setOptions` function should looks like this `(options: Partial<NativeStackNavigationOptions>) => void`

Comment: @captain-yossarian. You may check above the fourth attempt. It really wants the `HomeProps`.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you without reproducible example

Comment: @captain-yossarian Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rn-app-setoptions-rrm9z9?file=/src/App.test.tsx

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkM19N) works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import "react-native";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import { NativeStackScreenProps, NativeStackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

type RootStackParamList = {
  App: undefined;
};

export type AppProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "App">;

const App: FC<AppProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <View>hello</View>,
      gestureEnabled: false
    });
  });

  return <View>Hello</View>;
};

export default App;


const setOptions = (options: NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "App">) =>
  void (
    // 4

    render(
      <App navigation={options} route={{ key: 'hello', name: "App", }} />
    )
  );
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkM19N)

We need to use `NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "App">` type for `options`

Comment: The above works, but I cannot get the values from `render`. Is there a way to get `getByText` etc.?

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris I'm not sure what do you mean. COuld you plewase provide an example?

Comment: I modified the answer below. There from `render` I can extract `getByText`. (But I get the usual error again. It works only if I don't try to get anything). Is there a way to modify your answer, so I could extract values from `render`?

Comment: WHich `render` function are you using?

Comment: From react native testing library. I cannot get it from `screen.`. Check the old playground the last line please.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know which playfround link are you talking about. Could you please share the link ?

Comment: The link is too long and not accepted. A link to the playground is under your answer above. Thank you

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZr34m) example. I'm able to use getByText

Comment: Great it's working! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

Instead of `HomeProps` I should use `HomeNavigationProp` from the navigation types:

```js
export type HomeProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;

export type HomeNavigationProp = HomeProps['navigation'];
```

```js
describe('<HomeScreen />', () => {
  it('Renders correctly', () => {
    const navigation: HomeNavigationProp = null;

const { getByText } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <HomeScreen navigation={navigation} route={undefined} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>,

getByText("hello");
    )
  });
```