# Typescript: Partial typing a react-navigation spy helper

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

(This is somewhat related to [this three year-old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569447/how-to-mock-react-navigations-navigation-prop-for-unit-tests-with-typescript-in). I have tried to to follow the answers but they did not resolve my problem.)

I want to build a general mock (spy) navigator that I can pass in like I do here with `spyNavigation`:

```js
  it('shows an error if the request fails', async () => {
    const spyNavigation = {
      replace: jest.fn(),
      push: jest.fn(),
    }
    mockServer.use(
      rest.get('*/users/current-user', (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ id: 1 }))
      })
    )
    mockServer.use(
      rest.get('*/some-data', (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.status(500))
      })
    )

    // @ts-ignore
    TestHelper.renderWithReactQueryClient(<OverviewScreen navigation={spyNavigation} />)

    await TestHelper.waitForWithExtendedTimeOut(() => {
      expect(spyNavigation.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error', {
        error: new Error('Request failed with status code 500'),
      })
    })
  })
```

I would like to abstract the `spyNavigation` to a test helper and have TypeScript help me out to Partial typing it. So it will code-complete methods like 'replace', 'push' etc.

The TypeScript of `react-navigation` is just so complex for me to understand. It would be fine if the spy does not know about the names Screens/Navigators - just to be a general "navigation" object.

```js
import { BottomTabScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { CompositeScreenProps, NavigatorScreenParams } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { AxiosError } from 'axios'

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}

export type RootStackParamList = {
  SignInOrCreateUser: undefined
  SignIn: undefined
  Root: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined
  Modal: undefined
  Error: { error: AxiosError | null } | undefined
}

export type RootTabParamList = {
  Overview: undefined
  Returns: undefined
  Portfolio: undefined
  More: undefined
}

export type RouteName = keyof RootStackParamList | keyof RootTabParamList

export const routeTypeGuard = (route: RouteName) => route

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> = NativeStackScreenProps<
  RootStackParamList,
  Screen
>

export type RootTabScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootTabParamList> = CompositeScreenProps<
  BottomTabScreenProps<RootTabParamList, Screen>,
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
>
```

this does not work

```js
import { NativeStackNavigatorProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack/lib/typescript/src/types'

export const mockNavigation: NativeStackNavigatorProps = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  push: jest.fn(),
  replace: jest.fn(),
  pop: jest.fn(),
}
```

```
Type '{ navigate: jest.Mock<any, any>; push: jest.Mock<any, any>; replace: jest.Mock<any, any>; pop: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeStackNavigatorProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'navigate' does not exist in type 'NativeStackNavigatorProps'.ts(2322)
```

I have a guess that it should be something like

```js
export const mockNavigation: Record<keyof ???, () => ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>> = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  push: jest.fn(),
  replace: jest.fn(),
  pop: jest.fn(),
}
```

Comment: Hi. Hope I'm not missing something, but have you tried typing with `StackNavigationProp` type?

Comment: added that attempt to the question - it does not work @rexessilfie

Comment: guessing it should be something with `mockNavigation: Record<keyof ?????, () => ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>> `

Comment: Yep. That approach seems like it should work! I will post an answer attempting to fill in the types for the ????, and let me know if it works. It still uses `StackNavigationProp` which looks to have the functions you are looking to mock.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution to your question after your comments! I hope this works for you. I am extending the `StackNavigationProp` which has the names of the functions you want: `navigate`, `push` etc. Also from your question, I am replacing the types of its properties to be the return of `jest.fn`.

The optional generics for `MockStackNavigationProp`, should also mirror those of `StackNavigationProp`, allowing you to specify if `ParamList` if available.

If this works, I wonder if it could be taken further to also have the argument types of the jest function mocks, be automatically inferred from the original function definitions.

```
import { ParamListBase } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";

type MockStackNavigationProp<
  ParamList extends ParamListBase = any,
  RouteName extends keyof ParamList = string
> = Record<
  keyof StackNavigationProp<ParamList, RouteName>,
  ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>
>;

const mockNavigation: MockStackNavigationProp = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  pop: jest.fn(),
  push: jest.fn()
  //.. and more, OR use Partial<MockStackNavigationProp>
};
```

CodeSandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rn-mock-navigation-nugvuf?file=/src/testTypes.ts).

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works like a charm (only had change it to `import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'` since I'm using React Native.

Comment: Lovely. Glad to hear!